How to use GitLab CI needs dynamically with a parallel matrix?
I need to start the next job from the following stage as soon as the first job in the current stage finishes, without waiting for the other jobs in the current stage to complete.
I have gitlab CI stages
stages:
  - lint
  - plan
  - apply

With matrix
.terraform_path: &terraform_path
  - DIR:
      - "xxx"
      - "yyy"
      - "zzz"

First stage lint creates 3 jobs each from parallel matrix
lint:
  stage: lint
  parallel:
    matrix: *terraform_path
  script:
    - |
      terraform fmt -check -recursive -diff
      cd $DIR
      terraform init
      terraform validate
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
      - $DIR/.terraform

Next, plan
plan:
  stage: plan
  parallel:
    matrix: *terraform_path
  script:
    - |
      cd $DIR
      terraform init
      terraform plan -out=$PLAN -parallelism=30
      terraform show --json $PLAN | convert_report > $PLAN_JSON
  rules:
    - *run_if_no_lock
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $DIR/$PLAN
    reports:
      terraform: $DIR/$PLAN_JSON
  resource_group: $DIR

Then i try to add needs
plan:
  stage: plan
  needs:
    - job: lint-xxx
    - job: lint-yyy
    - job: lint-zzz

But this does not work. It also doesn't work if I use:
plan:
  stage: plan
  needs:
    - job: lint

Or
plan:
  stage: plan
  needs:
    - job: lint-$DIR

It doesn't recognize it.
So im expected when lint-xxx in first stage is over faster than other jobs in the same stage it will proceed to next stage plan without waiting other jobs

You need to use needs:parallel:matrix.
In your case, for instance:
plan:
  stage: plan
  needs:
    - job: lint
      parallel:
        matrix:
          - DIR: xxx
          - DIR: yyy

(The plan job would wait on the 2 lint jobs xxx and yyy but not the zzz one. To adapt according to what you want to do.)

No, it doesn't work. The plan:xxx stage waits for all jobs to finish before starting.
